# Airflow tasks not starting when they should be

Tags: python, parallel-processing, airflow

I have the following simple `DAG`:

```
dag = DAG('test_parallel',
        description='Simple tutorial DAG',
        schedule_interval=None,
        start_date=datetime(2017, 3, 20),
        catchup=False)


def first_echo(arg):
    print('\n\n')
    print('FIRST ECHO! %s' % arg)

def second_echo(arg):
    print('\n\n')
    print('SECOND ECHO! %s' % arg)

def final_echo():
    print('\n\n')
    print('FINAL ECHO: ')

final_echo = PythonOperator(task_id='final_echo' , dag=dag, provide_context=False, python_callable=final_echo)

for i in range(5):
    first_echo_op = PythonOperator(task_id='first_echo_%s' % i, python_callable=first_echo, op_args=[i], dag=dag)
    second_echo_op = PythonOperator(task_id='second_echo_%s' % i, python_callable=second_echo, op_args=[i], dag=dag)

    first_echo_op.set_downstream(second_echo_op)
    second_echo_op.set_downstream(final_echo)
```

The idea is that I have a series of five independent tasks, each which leads to a following task, and they all get aggregated to a final task.

The issue is that none of my `second_echo` tasks will start until all `first_echo` tasks finish.  Since the `first_echo` tasks are all **independent** and each of the `second_echo` tasks only depend on the previous independent `first_echo` task, I would've thought they would've run as soon as there are available resources to do so...

I can provide a Gantt chart if needed.

**The question is**: How do I make independent pathways in a DAG run as soon as they can, rather than wait for all first tasks to finish, assuming I have the proper amount of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Your DAG is is working as expected on my environment.

If I add a random delay to the first tasks, to force some to finish earlier, like so:

```
def first_echo(arg):
  time.sleep(random.randint(0, 30))
  print('\n\n')
  print('FIRST ECHO! %s' % arg)
```

I get the expected parallel execution pattern (using LocalExecutor):
[image]